# complex SQL depending on each object insert time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi so here is the table:

```
Select * from LogTable order by insert_time desc
```

LogTable:

```
|user_id|action|object_id|insert_time|
|2      |start |123      |20.04.2015 |
|2      |stop  |123      |19.04.2015 |
|2      |start |123      |17.04.2015 |
|1      |stop  |321      |16.04.2015 |
|1      |start |321      |12.04.2015 |
|3      |start |1234     |11.04.2015 |
|4      |start |12345    |5.04.2015  |
|4      |stop  |12345    |3.04.2015  |
...
```

Now I want to **select all user ids that have their own same object ever stopped but never started again**. As a result, **only user with id=1** should be selected. How should the sql query be written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would seem to want all users where the last value for `action` is `stop`.  Here is one method using `row_number()`:

```
select lt.*
from (select lt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, object_id
                                order by insert_time desc) as seqnum
      from logtable lt
     ) lt
where seqnum = 1 and action = 'stop';
```

Comment: maybe add objectid to patition, in case user has more than 1 object

Comment: @Capitaine . . . That is quite possible.  I found the question hard to follow in terms of how multiple object ids should be handled.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM LogTable T1 
WHERE T1.Action = 'stop'

AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM LogTable T2 
  WHERE T1.UserId = T2.UserId 
  AND T2.Action = 'start' 
  AND T1.insert_time < T2.insert_time
 )
```

[See sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d799/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`, verify two rows for the user_id, with different action values.

```
select user_id
from LogTable
group by user_id
having count(*) = 2
  and  count(distinct action) = 2
```

Comment: Actually there are more than just 2 actions (start and stop) in my case, and also it is also not suitable as the start action could be after the stop action. I don't want user id=2 to be selected..

Comment: @Capitaine nah, maybe with count(*) % 2 = 0 and count(distinct action) = 2. But i would not rely on this

Comment: I see. You mean you're looking for user_id's with exactly 1 start and exactly 1 stop?

Comment: the last value for action is stop as Gordon's answer

Comment: @Capitaine yes, it would work for the data in your example, but what if one user had stop, start, stop, start. This would have been restarted (hopefully last) but would not be selected with this query

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the record with max `insert_time` per `user_id` and select the record if it represents a `stop` action.

```
SELECT l.*
FROM LogTable l
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(insert_time) AS insert_time
            FROM LogTable
            GROUP BY user_id) t
ON t.user_id = l.user_id AND l.insert_time = t.insert_time
WHERE l.action = 'stop'
```

Answer (score -2):

`SELECT DISTINCT(userid) FROM (
  SELECT userid, action from LogTableorder 
  GROUP BY userid, object_id
  HAVING insert_time = max(insert_time)
) WHERE action=stop;`

Comment: your query is invalid because: you are not naming the subselect, can't use insert_time in your having since it is not in group by, stop should have been 'stop' - I should add that distinct is not a function, but unfortunately this part is valid

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works for the whole selected row! E.g. "select distinct(a), b" eq "select distinct a, b" eq "select distinct a, (b)"!

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.